# Eslint rule for space after asterisks in comment line

Tags: eslint

I have a problem that the **eslint** doesn't validate my **comment** correctly.

Below is the case:

```
/**
 *FieldName for react-hook-form.
 */
```

I want to set a rule so if I don't have a space after an asterisk(*) in a comment like mentioned in above **eslint** throws an error and the correct variant is:

```
/**
 * FieldName for react-hook-form.
 */
```

UPD:
my current config is:

```
{
'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': [
          'error',
          {
            contexts: [
              'TSPropertySignature',
              'TSIndexSignature',
              'TSEnumMember',
            ],
            require: {
              FunctionDeclaration: false,
            },
          },
        ],
}
```

Comment: Have you considered https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc or similar?